# I need to connect two USB cables but upon peeling them i have come across wires of totally different colour schemes, how to connect them?

Tags: usb

I need to connect two USB cables but upon peeling them i have come across wires of totally different color schemes. One USB cable has RED, WHITE, GREEN and BLACK wires. While the other cable has four wires of YELLOW, BLUE, GRAYISH WHITE and GREENISH colors. How to connect them? PLEASE help. Both the cables are of different joysticks.

Comment: Open up the joystick and look how things are connected inside it.  The VCC/GND lines should be easy to figure out, the D+/D- will be trickier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the electronics store and get a continuity tester. It is the simplest of test equipment. It has two probes, if the two probes are connected or connected via a wire then it beeps.

You use it to find which wire is connected to pin 1, then pin 2 etc. Connect 1 to 1, 2 to 2, etc.

Make sure you hold the connector the same way when assigning pin numbers, it is not uncommon for newbies to connect in mirror image.

You can get one for $5 (maybe less) or you can make one with an led, resistor and battery (this type does not beep). Or a light bulb and battery.

Comment: Why the downvote?  This answer is perfectly valid, and probably the best, if you want do this safely.  Randomly guessing about a poor color scheme will get you fried equipment.

Comment: Thanks. This answer helped. Though I did it without the tester. I just peeled of the connector, saw the connections and after some struggle with the scheme it started working.